# I/O "check if file name specified" args != 2 thing

Tags: java, args

Here is a fraction of my code.

```
if(args.length != 2) {
    System.out.println("Usage: copyFile from to");
    return;
}
```

The book I'm studying says that the code above is for:

> making sure that a file name has been specified

I don't understand why there is 2 in `if` does `args.length != 2` make sure that the file name has been specified?

I can't understand. Please help me out. And a little bit of detailed help
could be a lot of use for me. Thanks.

Comment: args.length checks for the number of given arguments. So it checks if you gave it 2 filenames.

Comment: This `if` makes sure that you call the program two parameter. `from` and `to`

Answer (score 1):

The usage in your code clearly mentions that

```
System.out.println("Usage: copyFile from to");
```

So, your code needs to check whether two filenames are passed to it or not!

First argument passed to the command-line should be SourceFile/Directory and the second argument should be DestinationFile/Directory where first one is to be copied.

hence,

```
if(args.length != 2) {
System.out.println("Usage: copyFile from to");
return;
}
```

and the code should be run as :-

```
java SourceClassName /path/of/source/file(folder) /path/of/destination/file(folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `args` hold the input to main method in Java class.
In Java `args` contains the supplied [command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) as an array of String objects.

For example running your class this way: `java yourProgram input1 input2` then args = {"input1", "input2"}

Acording to your code snipet **this if is checking that there are num of inputs different to 2**. If it's true, print the use message and return. That's all I can say: without more code I can't say why this if is checking what you say but this is how `args` variable works.

I guess your main method is expecting two inputs, maybe the first one the  filename you want to copy from and the second one the filename of the file you want to copy to.